# How to call different scripts based on url using if els statement

Tags: javascript

How can I run a specific .js script if url matches "/search" or run a different .js script if the url is different using if/else statement?  This would go in head section and either are used to build the DOM based on the url.

Would the code below work? Any help appreciated!

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/search') {
  <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>;
}
else {
  <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call external java script files conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579694/call-external-java-script-files-conditionally)

Comment: That is not how you add scripts dynamically. You want createElement and appendChild

Answer (score 2):

I think, we should to try to using

element.innerHTML = script

Into the if else area

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

During the page loading phase, you could use `document.write`.

```html
<script>
document.write(window.location.pathname === '/search' ? 
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"><\/script>' :
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```